# write multiline sqli query in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have more than 100 fields in table and i am trying to write mysqli query in php. At the moment my query is in one line. 
But it is bit hard to manage for me.

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4,Name5,Name6,Name7,Name8,Name9,Name10,Name11,Name12,Name13,Name14,Name15,Name16,Name17,Name18,Name19,Name20,Name21,Name22,Name23,Name24,Name25,Name26,Name27,Name28,Name29,Name30,Name31,Name32,Name33,Name34,Name35,Name36,Name37,Name38,Name39,Name40,Name41,Name42,Name43,Name44,Name45,Name46,Name47,Name48,Name49,Name50,Name51,Name52,Name53,Name54,Name55,Name56,Name57,Name58,Name59,Name60,Name61,Name62,Name63,Name64,Name65,Name66,Name67,Name68,Name69,Name70,Name71,Name72,Name73,Name74,Name75,Name76,Name77,Name78,Name79,Name80,Name81,Name82,Name83,Name84,Name85,Name86,Name87,Name88,Name89,Name90,Name91,Name92,Name93,Name94,Name95,Name96,Name97,Name98,Name99 FROM City LIMIT 10")) {
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);
/* free result set */
$result->close();
}
```

Above is the sample code.

I want to know how can i write it to multi-line. So, it will be easily manageable.

Comment: What do you mean by one line? Break the lines in two or more?

Comment: why dont you try `SELECT * FROM City LIMIT 10`

Comment: And if you need all fields just select *

Comment: I am new to php. Thats why i am asking for help. Anyways thanks for your comment and vote.

Comment: I don't need all fields. I need specific fields. and count of fields are more than 100

Comment: This is for my school project.

Comment: Have tried to put a enter somewhere?

Comment: use `select *` and remove the unwanted feilds using php

Comment: mega6382 can you give me an example.

Comment: I think you will get your answer with @SuperDJ comment.

Comment: If you have more than 100 fields in 1 table then  your database design is very very bad. Just try to split your data. You see you are not able to manage it at the moment

Comment: bub thanks for your comment. Can you please tell me how many fields can be created in table for good practice. Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In PHP, strings can span multiple lines:

```
$sql = "
SELECT name1, name2
FROM table
";
```

You can also use concatenation (making sure you remember spaces):

```
$sql =
  "SELECT name1, name2".
  " FROM table";
```

Or, you can create your SQL dynamically:

```
$fields = Array("name1", "name");
$fieldlist = implode(", ", $fields);
$sql = "SELECT $fieldlist FROM table";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not able to vote as i don't have enough reputation.

Comment: No worries. But do also pay attention to @bub's comment - it is a code smell when you have that many fields in a table, there's almost certainly a better way to structure your database. "How" is a bit of a topic, but involves [database normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). We can't say anything more unless we actually see your database schema.

Answer (score 4):

All my queries are formatted like this:

```
$query = "SELECT "
          . " col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, "
          . " col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15, col16, col17 "
          . " FROM table " 
          . " WHERE col1 = $val";
```

As much as this seems a little inefficient, it really helps managing the queries, I usuall continue the columns until I would have to scroll horizontally.

Also, I noticed that the database will be really inefficient, could you tell us what you try to save in the DB and why this many columns in one table? (do realize that storing so many fields in one table is a bad practice and that you should split the data.)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10890072)

Comment: @misterion While I agree that this is not the perfect post/answer, I would like to point out that I did provide a way to make 100+ columns more readable and manageable and while I was at it I tried to get the author to disclose information to let me help him in building a "better" database model which would leave the managing requirement out of the original question. correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 3):

In PHP code you can write multiline queries

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4,Name5,
Name6,Name7,Name8,Name9,Name10,
Name11,Name12,Name13,Name14,Name15,
Name16,Name17,Name18,Name19,Name20,
Name21,Name22,Name23,Name24,Name25,
Name26,Name27,Name28,Name29,Name30,
Name31,Name32,Name33,Name34,Name35,
Name36,Name37,Name38,Name39,Name40,
Name41,Name42,Name43,Name44,Name45,
Name46,Name47,Name48,Name49,Name50,
Name51,Name52,Name53,Name54,Name55,
Name56,Name57,Name58,Name59,Name60,
Name61,Name62,Name63,Name64,Name65,
Name66,Name67,Name68,Name69,Name70,
Name71,Name72,Name73,Name74,Name75,
Name76,Name77,Name78,Name79,Name80,
Name81,Name82,Name83,Name84,Name85,
Name86,Name87,Name88,Name89,Name90,
Name91,Name92,Name93,Name94,Name95,
Name96,Name97,Name98,Name99 
FROM City 
LIMIT 10")) {
printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);
/* free result set */
$result->close();
```

The code listed above will work absolutely correct

Answer (score 2):

You can write this query in a manageable way like this:

```
$query = "SELECT name1, name2, name3," .
         "name4" .
         "FROM table" .
         "WHERE name1=$var";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

**OR**

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT name1, name2, name3," .
             "name4" .
             "FROM table" .
             "WHERE name1=$var");
```

This looks cleaner and reduce the chances you mess with quotes `"` `'`.

This is just my suggestion not a standard. Hope this helps! ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't vote as don't have enough reputation.